# Way to make a div horizontally scrollable without cutting vertical?

Tags: css, overflow

I have a dropdown-menu in a table, with the Bootstrap class table-responsive and its cutting out parts of the dropdown, I was looking to write my own CSS class which should wrap horizontal overflow but show vertical overflow.

As soon as I give the div, containing the table, the properties overflow-y: scroll, both overflows, x, and y, get wrapped.

Is there any way to only wrap the horizontal overflow?

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Your question is unclear; "wrap the horizontal overflow" is the opposite of "horizontally scrollable". So can you clarify a bit?